# Using rails 4 how do I send data via ajax controller method and return a object id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I feel like this should be simple but I am new to ajax and using ajax in rails.

If the a user follows a link to my site, that link will contain a token.  On page load, I am grabbing that token.

I need to send the token to a controller method (I think), lookup a user via the token, and send that user_id back to the ajax call.

I have the token in a js var.  And I have a controller method but am stuck there.

many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have the User ID beforehand, it's harder to have a RESTful structure in the Controller, though you could have a `from_token` action in your `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #...

  def from_token
    user = User.find_by_token(params[:token])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {user: {id: user.id}} }
    end
  end
end
```

And in routes.rb:

```
#...

resources :users do
  get 'from_token' => 'users#from_token'
end
```

Depending on what data you want for the JavaScript, it may be easier to return all the user data, rather than just the ID. In which case [have a look at jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) for building more complex JSON objects.

In terms of the JavaScript, it depends on what framework you're using to make the ajax request in the browser. If it's jQuery (the Rails default) use the [ajax get request API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

```
var token = '{{extracted token}}';
$.get('/users/from_token.json?token=' + token, function(data) {
  var userId = data.user.id;
});
```

Comment: I had to make two changes to get this to work.  I'll note them in your answer and you can format the edits, and I'll accept the answer